# How to reproduce MATLAB's normal distribution random numbers?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, random

I'm porting a project from MATLAB to Python and it turns out that while uniform distribution random generator are identical in NumPy and MATLAB, the numbers for normal distribution are slightly different. After some googling I've found out that the reason is different algorithms of transformation from uniform to normal distribution. MATLAB uses Ziggurat algorithm by default and NumPy uses Box-Muller if I'm not mistaken.

Our MATLAB project uses Phased Array Toolbox, so there's no way to insert our own generator into it.

Is there any way to reproduce MATLAB's normal distribution random generator in Python or C/C++?

Comment: what about http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/ziggurat/ziggurat.html?

Comment: What do you mean by "reproduce"? Identical values down to the bit? The same speed? This [paper](http://www.doornik.com/research/ziggurat.pdf) (PDF) and this [C code](http://www.doornik.com/research/ziggurat_code.zip) (ZIP) is another good source that I've used myself. Neither this, nor the code linked to by @SeverinPappadeux, is likely to give you the same sequence of normal random variates however. Even if they mostly did, difference in math libraries, and even compilers, could also result in small variations.

Comment: AFAIK, he wants the values to be reproducible. At least with delta about 10^-6. Bit-to-bit match is not obligatory.

Comment: You could also change the method Matlab used to generate normal variates using the [`'NormalTransform'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randstream.html#brtliy_) of the [`RandStream`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randstream.randstream.html) class and see if the variates match then.